# jQuery Click input and Function?

Tags: jquery, click, submit

I have this HTML

```
<div class="someclass">                
   <input id="special" type="submit" value="Post"/>                                      
</div>
```

And I'm confused as to how I can run jQuery to click and run a function ? i.e. this works

```
<div class="someclass">                
   <input id="special" type="submit" value="Post" onclick="specialFunction();"/>                                      
</div>
```

But this doesn't ?

```
jQuery('#special').click(function () {
    specialFunction();
});
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Probably because you did not put that code inside the `ready` event handler: http://api.jquery.com/ready/ . It works: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/E8nhw/ I suggest you read a tutorial: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#special').click(function () {
        specialFunction();
        return false;
    });
});
```

but I recommend that you use the live instruction in order to apply to any links that may appear later, doing so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#special').live("click", function() {
        specialFunction();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: There can always only be **one** element with a certain ID. Using `live` does not make sense here. It is not an universal remedy.

Comment: You have lost for this reason I always prefer utulizzare classes, you may make a special class if possible, of course! : D

Answer (score 2):

Jquery needs some time to load. Therefore you need to use the ready() method of jQuery to load eventlisteners once the DOM is ready.

Second think is that you use a submit button. You need to cancel its natural behavior otherwise the browser will perform the js action and also submit the form.

Your js code should work like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#special').click(function () { specialFunction(); });    
});
```

Consider using  tag instead of input button with type submit, or add "return false;" to cancel natural behaviour of the browser.

Best regards,
Paul

Comment: It's not because jQuery needs time to load. It's because if the code is in the `head`, the DOM is not built yet. But jQuery is definitely available if you put the code after the `script` tag which loads jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Add this code `return false;` block to the end of onclick attribute's value.

It is happens, because you button submit form by click.

And use `$(document).ready();`

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
jQuery('#special').click(function () {
    specialFunction();
});
```

to this:

```
$('#special').click(function () {
    specialFunction();
    return false;
});
```

Have a look - http://jsfiddle.net/ajthomascouk/y52fr/

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you attach the event when the element is ready and available in the document. Either put the event binding script after the element in the document, or use the [ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) event on the document and bind the event inside (preferred).

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#special').click(specialFunction);
}):
```

If you're intending to process the form without submitting it, you need to prevent the default browser action. The correct way to do it via jQuery is using the [preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) event method.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#special').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        specialFunction();
    });
}):
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#special").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  specialFunction();
});
```